# Regular expressions and how to get captured values

Tags: python, regex

```
custom = 'number=value1;user=value2;yr=value3'

number=re.findall('number=(.+?);',custom)
user=re.findall('user=(.+?);',custom)
yr=re.findall('yr=(.+?)[;\w]',custom))

outcome:

print number
value1
```

I am trying to extract value of `number`, `user`,and `yr` from `custom`. It is working except 'yr', because since 'yr' is last word it does not end with ';'. I tried adding \w, but not working. Is there way to add ends with either ';' or end of string? I could search for `custom[-1]`, but I just want to know how to do in regex, and `yr` is not always last; `number` or `user` can be last sometimes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can leverage the regex lookbehind and use a regex like this:

```
(?<==)(\w+)
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/uL7iD0/1)**

[image]

So, you can use this regex for each case:

```
(?<=number=)(\w+)
(?<=user=)(\w+)
(?<=yr=)(\w+)
```

You can have your code as this:

```
custom = 'number=value1;user=value2;yr=value3'

number=re.findall('(?<=number=)(\w+)',custom)
user=re.findall('(?<=user=)(\w+)',custom)
yr=re.findall('(?<=yr=)(\w+)',custom))

outcome:

print number
value1
```

**Update**: as **[CommuSoft](https://stackoverflow.com/users/67579/commusoft)** pointed in his comment, the regex won't capture the content if you have spaces. So, you can improve the regex by using:

```
(?<==)([^;]+)
```

So, you can have for each parameter something like this:

```
(?<=number=)([^;]+)
(?<=user=)([^;]+)
(?<=yr=)([^;]+)
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/uL7iD0/2)**

Comment: Look behind with an arbitrary length is in many cases not implement very efficiently. Especially because it can make regexes Turing complete. Although the answer is correct, it not adviseable.

Comment: Sorry @CommuSoft, why do you say an arbitrary length? It is a fixed length. What am I missing?

Comment: well now it is fixed. The only remaining problem is your regex will break of on non words. If the entry is `user=Richard Matthew;`, then it will only capture `Richard`. I think it is safer to use semi-coma's as delimiters.

Answer (score 1):

`\w` matches any word character but you want to match the end of the string.
You can use instead:
`yr=(.+?)(?:;|$)`

Also for learning/debugging regexes there are regex testers like this one:
https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
number, user, yr = re.findall('(?<==)[^;]+', custom)
print number, user, yr
```

**Result:** `value1 value2 value3`

Comment: `$` in a box (`[$]`) is interpreted as a dollar character I think. Removing it results in the same behavior.

Comment: @CommuSoft: You are right..it will match literally..its not needed as the last pattern will be chosen anyway as there is no `;` at last and regex has reached the end of line..answer edited..

Answer (score 1):

`\w` means a word character. Now since you made the regex "ungreedy" the regex wants to terminate the group as soon as possible, so it will match only the first character, and match the remainder with `\w`. You can however use:

```
(;|$)
```

So this results in:

```
yr=re.findall('yr=(.+?)(?:;|$)',custom)
```

which gives the correct result

The reason the `?:` is added in the front is because you don't want to capture it (show it in the output).